# Is it possible to override filter lookup with predefined values with custom Manager/Queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-managers

I am trying to implement the behaviour for my models so that when you are deleting the object(s) it is not deleting physically, but just add some attribute to state that it was deleted.

So I created custom queryset, manager and mixin to apply for each created model:

```
class StateQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def delete(self):
        self.update(active=False)

class StateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return StateQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db).filter(active=True)

class ModelMixin(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = StateManager()

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.active = False
        self.save()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And the models:

```
class Organizer(ModelMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class EventData(ModelMixin, models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    organizer = models.ForeignKey(Organizer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So, the idea, is when I do any:

```
Organizer.objects.all() / Organizer.objects.filter(name__startswith='<some_start_prefix>')
```

I will recieve Organizer objects only which are active=True (i.e. "not deleted").
All looks good, but when I have related objects, there is an issue.
If, for example, I do:

```
EventData.objects.filter(organizer__name__startswith='<some_start_prefix>')
```

It will return all EventData objects even the 'deleted'.
But if I do:

```
EventData.objects.filter(organizer__name__startswith='<some_start_prefix>', organizer__active=True)
```

All works as expected and only 'active' records returned. So I don't want to use:

> organizer__active=True

for each query in the views.

I've read the docs but still don't understand how to create this with custom Manager and QuerySet. Could you please help, or guide how to do this? What I am missing?

So to summarize: when I do:

```
EventData.objects.filter(organizer__name__startswith='<some_start_prefix>')
```

I want to recieve all EventData objects where Organizer.active set to True, but without writing additional organizer__active=True each time in the client code. Is it possible to do it in the Manager or QuerySet?

Comment: Can you just clarify, having `organizer__active=True` in your filter gives you the results that you want, but you don't want that in your query?

Comment: @markwalker_ no, I want, I just want it to be in some generic place. I don't want to add it in all the places I use it each time in views (for example). As many as I understand it is possible to do it through custom managers and querysets, but I don't understand how.

As many as you can see I have in get_queryset:
StateQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db).filter(active=True) 

So for each get/filter done on model it will return only the 'active'. But it not works for related objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you can indeed add some custom queries to your model's queryset.

You might do something like;

```py
def filter_active_organizer(self, prefix):
    return self.filter(organizer__name__startswith=prefix, organizer__active=True)
```

Let me illustrate with something from a project I've got;

```py
from django.db.models import Q, QuerySet
from django.utils import timezone


class EventQuerySet(QuerySet):
    """
    Custom queryset/manager for the Event model...adds common filtering
    operations
    """
    def filter_open(self):
        """
        Filter events in this queryset to only include those whose entry
        process is currently open.
        """
        now = timezone.now()

        return self.filter(
            Q(entry_open__isnull=True) | Q(entry_open__lte=now),
            Q(entry_close__isnull=True) | Q(entry_close__gt=now)
        )

    def filter_closed(self):
        """
        Filter events in this queryset to only include those whose entry
        process is currently closed.
        """
        now = timezone.now()

        return self.filter(
            (Q(entry_open__isnull=False) & Q(entry_open__gt=now)) |
            (Q(entry_close__isnull=False) & Q(entry_close__lte=now))
        )


EventManager = EventQuerySet.as_manager()
```

```py
class Event(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'entry'
        verbose_name = _('Event')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Events')

    objects = EventManager
```

These queries can then be accessed using `Event.objects.filter_open()` or added to admin with a filter class;

```py
class FilterStatus(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    """
    List filter to filter events by whether they are open or closed
    (this is a computed value)
    """
    title = 'entry status'
    parameter_name = 'entry_status'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        """
        Return the lookup choices for this filter
        """
        return [
            ('open', _('Open')),
            ('closed', _('Closed')),
        ]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        """
        Perform the filtering (if required)
        """
        if self.value() == 'open':
            return queryset.filter_open()

        if self.value() == 'closed':
            return queryset.filter_closed()

        return queryset
```

Comment: Thank you for the offering a solutionn @markwalker_ but this is not I expected to see. I know that I can set a method, which will return me the filtered queryset by some criteria, but it's not working as a default one, so to be working for related objects, I need define multiple methods for querysets/models.

p.s. As many as I investigated, at the time it's not working as I expect ...

Comment: It's probably worth updating your question with what you've written & what you expect.